# Windows Server 2012 Core + Startup programs

Tags: startup, windows-server-2012

Im new to windows server and I have some batch files I want to be run automatically on startup.
I have tried putting the scripts in the                   "%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" folder but that only works when the "GUI" is enabled.

NOTE: The server is running in core mode

Can someone please help me with this as it is doing my head in!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried editing the local policies on that server (gpedit.msc), and add what you need to:

```
Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts
```